# PermissionRequiredMixin AccessMixin permission_denied_message

Tags: python, django

OK so I don't know why django displays a "403 Forbidden" when PermissionDenied exception is raised with the permission_denied_message variable also inserted. I would like to display my own custom message. Not sure what am doing wrong though. Here is my code

```
class ProfileFormView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'shop_buy.change_userprofile'
    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = 'Permission Denied'
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['location', 'gender', 'profile_picture']
    template_name_suffix = '_form'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view):

> Django has a view to handle 403 Forbidden errors... This view loads and renders the template `403.html` in your root template directory, or if this file does not exist, instead serves the text “403 Forbidden”, as per RFC 7231#section-6.5.3 (the HTTP 1.1 Specification).

So the default response is just two words: "403 Forbidden" - it doesn't show the exception message. If you want to display the exception (which is available in the view context) you need to provide your own `403.html` template which displays it. Something like this would work:

```
<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
<p>{{ exception }}</p>
```

Note that the exception only became available in the template in Django 1.9.

Also note that you may not always want to make the contents of the exception public!

Comment: Please in which directory would this template be and would I need to reference it in the view context?

Comment: In the root of your app's `templates` directory. You don't need to reference it as this is the default.

Comment: Ok, so that worked out as expected. What if I want the permission exception raised not when a the view is requested but when attempting to POST it? How would I customize the ProfileFormView to accommodate this? Thank you.

Comment: I am unable to get `{{ exception }}` to display in the error page _403.html_. Could you have a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167348/how-to-display-permission-denied-message-in-custom-403-html-page-in-django)?